# How to create new ReplaySubjects on each click in stackblitz example?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Im learning rxjs subjects specifically ReplaySubjects. I want to adapt this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-behaviorsubject-mouseclicks-1sybjt so that each new click creates a new subscriber to demonstrate the ReplaySubject properties. Thats not how it currently works - new cells are showing the same value is because (I think) they are all displaying a single subject but i'm having problems understanding where to insert creation of the new subscriber. Any advice or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're returning `subject` to `mergeMap` so it is creating new subscriptions on every click.

Comment: The link is broken. Please add the relevant code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

original link is now broken (sorry not mine) but i solved my question here. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-behaviorsubject-mouseclicks-ndcysb

its a bit more simplistic than the original example for learning how replaysubject and subscribers work as i have made the subscription explicit.

```
console.clear();
import { BehaviorSubject, Subject, ReplaySubject, fromEvent, interval, merge } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const setElementText = (elemId, text) => 
  document.getElementById(elemId).innerText = text.toString();

const addHtmlElement = coords => document.body.innerHTML += `
  <div 
    id=${coords.id}
    style="
      position: absolute;
      height: 30px;
      width: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      top: ${coords.y}px;
      left: ${coords.x}px;
      background: ${rgb()};
      border-radius: 80%;"
    >
  </div>`;

const subject = new ReplaySubject(5);

function randomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function rgb(min=0, max=255)
{
  var r = randomInt(min, max);
  var g = randomInt(min, max);
  var b = randomInt(min, max);
  return `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, 0.5)`;
}

const click$ = fromEvent(document, 'click').pipe(
  map((e: MouseEvent) => ({ 
    x: e.clientX,
    y: e.clientY,
    id: Math.random() })),
  tap(coords => addHtmlElement(coords)),
  tap(function(coords) {
    console.log("new subscriber!");
    var subscriber = subject.subscribe(function(x) {
      console.log("coords.id, x", coords.id, x);
      setElementText(coords.id, x)
    });
  }),
);

const interval$ = interval(2000).pipe(
  tap(v => subject.next(v)),
  tap(v => setElementText('intervalValue', v))
);

merge(click$, interval$).subscribe();
```